# Как сделать перевод строки без отступа?

Tags: python, python-3.5, print

При  переводе строки новая строка имеет пробел. Как избавиться от него?

```
print (a, '\n', c, '\n', b)
```

Comment: Есть такая штука как `strip` почитайте о данной функции и все сразу станет ясно. Там также найдете `lstrip` и `rstrip`, что означает убрать левый или правый пробел, а `strip` убирает и справа и слева.

Comment: And, дело не в том, что у автора вопроса пробелы в самих строках, а в том, что print вставляет пробелы если печатать через него сразу несколько значений. И strip в данной ситуации никак не поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы печатаете  с помощью `print` несколько значений, то между ними будет вставляться разделитель. По умолчанию разделителем является пробел. Но с помощью аргумента `sep` можно установить в качестве разделителя вообще любое строковое значение.

В том числе, можно установить в качестве разделителя пустую строку, и тогда никакого разделителя вообще не будет.

```
print ('a', '\n', 'c', '\n', 'b', sep='')
```

Кстати, вы можете установить в качестве разделителя перевод строки, и тогда вам не нужно будет вставлять его после каждого значения.

Например, этот код напечатает каждое значение на отдельной строке, как вам и нужно:

```
print ('a', 'c', 'b', sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('a', '\n', 'c', '\n', 'b')
a 
 c 
 b

print ("{}\n{}\n{}".format('a', 'c', 'b'))
a
c
b
```